# Generate random unix timestamp

Tags: java, unix-timestamp

How I can generate random unix timestamp in specific times. For example get random unix time  mean between today and tomorrow.

Comment: maybe you can find something useful here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/java-generating-random-number-in-a-range

Answer (score 3):

```
long randomEpoch = epoch1 + Math.abs(new Random().nextLong()) % (epoch2-epoch1);
```

where `epoch1` and `epoch2` are the two times.

Comment: very good! I did: new Date(Math.abs(new Random().nextLong()) % new Date().getTime()) to get a random date between 1/1/1970 to today

Answer (score 1):

Get the needed range by generating two timestamps. Subtract the difference (absolute value). Get a random number between 0 and 1. Multiply the difference by the random number. Add the result to the earlier timestmap.

Answer (score 0):

This code specifically gets a random time between today and tomorrow.

```
public Date randTime(){
    Date now = new Date();
    Date today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDay(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    return new Date(today.getTime() + (long)(Math.random() * 86400000));
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `(long)(Math.random() * 86400000)`

Comment: Indeed. milliseconds, not seconds XD